# Getting a C GObject pointer from a Python gobject

Tags: python, webkit, gobject

I'm working with pywebkitgtk, which is a codegen'd binding- so there are a ton of GObject subclasses. The binding isn't complete, and I use ctypes to do a bunch of stuff in addition.

But now I need to use an object I've got- in Python- as an argument to a ctypes library call. Clearly, that won't work, and passing the memory address of the Python object isn't really a winner, either. How can I get a memory reference to the GObject backing the Python object?

Here's an example of something that doesn't work, but might give you an idea what I'm talking about.

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> libwebkit = ctypes.CDLL('libwebkit-1.0.so')
>>> import webkit
>>> webview = webkit.WebView()
>>> libwebkit.webkit_web_view_get_zoom_level(webview) #yes, I know the binding exposes this
ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 1
```

Again, this is just an example to illustrate the point- I want memory refs for gobjects to use with ctypes.